# Retrieve Customer's default and active card from Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to retrieve the default and active card of a Customer. (Also keep in mind that with the coding I have, the customer can always have one card which means if there is a way around it it can help).

Some months ago I used this code segment which was working fine. It seems Stripe made some updates and I can't get it to work now.

```
current_user.stripe_card_id = customer.active_card.id
```

The error I get is

> undefined method `active_card' for #Stripe::Customer

If you need any more information please let me know.

edit: `customer.default_card.id` does not work either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used customer.methods to check the methods and found this (default_source):

```
current_user.stripe_card_id = customer.default_source
```

Works fine now. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

default card id will available in **customer object's  `"default_source"`** key

```
{
  "id": "cus_GACkqbqFD8RQw4",
  "object": "customer",
  "default_source": <DEFAULT CARD ID HERE> 
   ...
}
```

read more here : https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers

**[EDIT] Additionally,**
It's worth noting that when you request a list of all the cards belonging to a particular customer, the default card is always at the top of the result. So you could also get the default card by requesting the customers cards and adding a limit of 1.

Information on how to achieve this: https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list

Answer (score 2):

**PaymentMethods API - 2020 update**

If you have switched from old *Sources API* to the new *Payment Methods API* then you should know that unlike old *Sources* there's no default *Payment Method* for a Customer.

Now, you can attach a Payment Method as default one to a subscription object:

```
Stripe::Subscription.update(
  'sub_8epEF0PuRhmltU',
  {
    default_payment_method: 'pm_1F0c9v2eZvKYlo2CJDeTrB4n',
  }
)
```

or as a `customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method`

```
Stripe::Customer.update(
  'cus_FOcc5sbh3ZQpAU',
  {
    invoice_settings: {default_payment_method: 'pm_1vvc9v2eZvKYlo2CJDeTrB4n'},
  }
)
```

Here is the whole [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/update-payment-details#customer-default) on that

Comment: Will the customer object's "default_source" key works after following PaymentMethods API - 2020 update. If else then how do I show last four digits of customer's card. And how to accomplish change default card source.

Comment: @jones It will work in some scenarios. For example, if you confirm a payment_intent without a payment_method, it will try to use the customer's default_source. However, you cannot directly set the payment_intent's payment_method to default_source.

The inconsistency is confusing and frustrating. I am currently figuring out how to smoothly migrate our users to payment_methods.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on customers' `default_source` is safe no matter the changes. You can see [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-default_payment_method) that subscriptions will still use customers' `default_source` if both `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` and `subscription.default_payment_method` are not set.

Answer (score -2):

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer_id_on_stripe)

first_3_cards = customer.sources.all(limit: 3, object: 'card')[:data]
```

Will return array of cards, if you want to fetch bank_accounts

```
first_3_bank_accounts = customer.sources.all(limit: 3, object: 'bank_account')[:data]
```

Comment: Does not answer the question at all. He was looking to see if it's possible to retrieve the default source of payment for a customer, not all the payment sources available.